# Load data from web service using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble to load some data from a web service. I created this factory:

```
.factory('urlService', function($http) {
  var service = {
  getURLStatus: function(urlElgg){
    var urlElgg = 'http://'+urlElgg+'/services/api/rest/xml/?method=system.api.list';
    $http({method: 'GET', url: urlElgg}).
      success(function(data) {
        console.log("success");
      }).
      error(function(data) {
        console.log("error");
      });
    }
  };
  return service;
})
```

And I have this in the controller:

```
  $scope.doAddCommunity = function() {
    console.log('Doing Add Community', $scope.communityData.url);
    urlService.getURLStatus($scope.communityData.url);
  };
```

Everything looks OK, but when I send an url always get "error" instead of "success". What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ? Try using `angular.toJson(data)` in the `console.log()` on the Error callback and post the error message here.

Comment: I'm not receiving any error message, only the code goes to the error part of the $http function, so I receive the string "error" as the result.

Comment: Please do what @jsfrocha said, replace `console.log("error")` with `console.log(data)` and tell us what you get in the console.

Comment: You are not receiving any error message because you are not "asking" for it. If the code "goes to the error part" it also receives a `data` object, which you can log by doing `console.log(angular.toJson(data))` in that part and checking its value in the browser console.

Comment: When I do that the only that I get is an empty result ""

Comment: you probably doing a CORS?? if thats the case, use jsonp. sytax - $http
.jsonp("URI?callback=JSON_CALLBACK");

Comment: Before doing the `$http` request print the URL with `console.log(urlElgg)` and tell us what you get. Then try to enter that URL directly on a browser windows and check if it works.

Comment: The URL that I get at that point is OK "http://app.coldtrick.com/services/api/rest/xml/?method=system.api.list", and it works in the browser

Comment: Is your app running/deployed in the same domain - app.coldtrick.com ?

Comment: No, is running in another domain.

Comment: @pabloasc since your code and the API URL are in different domains, you need to use jsonp - refer to my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is cross-domain request problem. In order to understand it, please take a moment to read the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Since you are not able to do the request "as it is", it means CORS is not enabled. Your other option is to use JSONP, however I don't think JSONP is currently supported by the app.coldtrick.com API.

Unless one of these options is enabled on the server-side, you will not be able to do those requests directly from the JS application.